# An appropiate graph visualization?

Tags: thesis, graphics

I want to include a plot in my thesis to highlight regional differences in bicycle collision outcomes. Now there are several plot visualizations I could use, and I am not sure which one could be the most appropriate. Having a "scale free" y axis better highlights the differences between each region, but it may also confuse the reader.

I am aware that there might not be an optimal solution to this, but I would appreciate to hear your thoughts.(If you have a completely other suggestion for an appropriate plot than the ones below, I would also be happy to hear those).

These are the plots I have made:

**Plot 1**
[image: plot 1]
**Plot 2**
[image: plot 2]
**Plot 3**
[image: plot 3]
**Plot 4**
[image: plot 4]

Comment: This question would better fit the scope of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. You could also try stacking bars by type of accident or type of area btw.

Answer (score -1):

It might be good to consider a broken y-axis. See this [example](https://peltiertech.com/broken-y-axis-in-excel-chart/). In your case, you only apply it to bicycle-only and bicycle-car.

Comment: Many people dislike broken axis, including [Hadley](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/jSrL_FnS8kc/MvzM_2_jiSIJ) who created the software the OP is using to create their plots.